# Skip requesting scopes in oauth flow in express-gateway UI

Tags: express-gateway

Try to use oAuth authorization flow. I get interface with requesting access to account in express gateway UI. [image]

Can I tune flow so that this interface is skipped and all requesting scopes was approved by default?

Answer (score 0):

You surely can, but you will have to clone the source code and change the html code directly from there. Unfortunately we have no way to use a plugin to change the page

Comment: is there flow, when I just get oauth access_token through api with basic auth credentials, not using UI?